# Как поставить точку остановки breakpoint в coffeescript в rubymine или других продуктах jetbrains

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, breakpoint, webstorm

Как поставить точку остановки breakpoint в `coffeescript` в `rubymine,phpstorm,...` или любых других продуктах `jetbrains` так чтобы в результате подключенный скомпилированный js, остановился на этом месте для debug. Желательно в связке в chrome. Точку остановки хотелось бы поставить слева крассная точка как на картинке примера.[image: Картинка как хотелось бы ставить точку остановки]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

точка останова ставится обычным образом - достаточно кликнуть в поле слева (как и показано на Вашем рисунке). Никаких специальных настроек не нужно - если Ваш coffeescript компилятор, генерирующий javascript из coffee, создает правильные сорсмапы, этого должно быть достаточно. См. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Debugging+client-side+CoffeeScript+and+TypeScript